# Gradle Unable to resolve sikulixapi

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gradle, dependency-management

I'm trying to change my project from Maven to Gradle and I have problem with some dependencies.

here is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'de.myurl.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'jxgrabkey', name: 'jxgrabkey', version: '1.0'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:3.9.1'
    compile 'net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:4.0.0'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'com.sikulix:sikulixapi:1.1.0'
    compile 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.4.0'
    compile 'com.relevantcodes:extentreports:2.41.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    compile 'javax.activation:activation:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.sun.xml.ws:policy:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.sun.jmx:jmxri:1.2.1'
    compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4'
    compile 'com.uttesh:pdfngreport:2.1.3'
    compile 'org.uncommons:reportng:1.1.4'
    compile 'org.testng:testng:7.0.0'
}
```

and here is the problem with the dependencies:

[image]

I also tried to use other versions of sikuli but that didn't work either.
is it possible that this problem is related to the structure of my project?

I really appreciate any helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have shown in the screenshot, Gradle tries to resolve a dependency called `com.sikulix:${sikulix.libs}:1.1.0`. Of cause, there is a place holder here called `${sikulix.libs}` that hasn't been substituted.

The place holder is actually defined in a Maven profile in the [pom file for sikuli](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sikulix/sikulixapi/1.1.0/sikulixapi-1.1.0.pom). The relevant parts are these:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Windows</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sikulix.libs>sikulixlibswin</sikulix.libs>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>Unix</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>unix</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sikulix.libs>sikulixlibslux</sikulix.libs>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>Mac</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>mac</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sikulix.libs>sikulixlibsmac</sikulix.libs>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<!-- ... -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
    <artifactId>${sikulix.libs}</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately, Gradle doesn't support Maven profiles so you have to create a substitution rule yourself to fix it. You can do it like this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.name == '${sikulix.libs}') {
            def os = org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current()
            def targetName
            if (os.isWindows()) {
                targetName = 'sikulixlibswin'
            } else if (os.isUnix()) {
                targetName = 'sikulixlibslux'
            } else if (os.isMacOsX()) {
                targetName = 'sikulixlibsmac'
            } else {
                throw new GradleException("Unknow operating system for determining the sikulix distribution")
            }
            details.useTarget group: details.requested.group, name: targetName, version: details.requested.version
            details.because 'The Maven dependency is relying on profiles to select the correct module name for the current operating system'
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using version 1.1.0, you may also have to define an additional Maven repository for one of the transitive dependencies called `jxgrabkey`. This repository is also defined in the pom, but will not be automatically used by Gradle. You can add it like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url = 'http://mvn.is.inf.uni-due.de:8081/nexus/content/repositories/atunes-dependencies/'
    }
}
```

But if you upgrade to the latest 1.1.1, this will not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

try adding additional maven repo:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/'
    }
}
```

And add grouping for sikuli

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.sikuli', name: 'sikuli-api', version: '1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: I also did that, but the same problem happens. Is there anything else that should be checked?

Comment: try newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Maven has also an id to be converted:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>testName</groupId>
        <artifactId>testName</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

will be converted to Gradle with this notation:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'testName:testName:1.1.1' 
}
```

Also try to use **implementation** instead of **compile.** after 2018 is deprecated syntax.

If build is not succeeded from this change try instead of **implementation** to use **api** as declaration. 
ex. `api 'com.sikulix:sikulixapi:1.1.0'`

After all it is a good choice to update library if applicable.

Hope that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me this way

```
dependencies {
    ... 
    compile files('sikulifolder/sikulixapi.jar')
    ...
}
```

sikulifolder - is a folder with jar in my project directory.
And don't forget that the dependencies order is important.
I set it before the last selenium dependencies for example.